# mean value property and the poisson kernel

Tags: complex-analysis

d[image: page1]
How do I proceed? I have the cauchy integral formula as $f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz$. But I am not sure how to proceed.I would appreciate some headway. Thank you for the hints below.

For part (iii), I am using the hint given in the problem, and considering,
$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma, 0,1} f(w) \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1+s/w}{1-s/w}) dw + \int_{\gamma,0,1} f(w) \frac{1}{2}\frac{1+sw}{1-sw}dw$. How do I compute this integral in two different ways?

Comment: Let $z=z_0+re^{i\theta}$.  Then, $z-z_0=re^{i\theta}$ and $dz=ire^{i\theta}\,d\theta$.  Can you proceed now?

Comment: For part (ii), can I express $f(z_0) = u(z_0)+iv(z_0)$.And do the same for the RHS of the conclusion of part(i).Then the result trivially appears. Is this correct?

Comment: @MarkViola, thank you. My question was how can I just make the assumption that $z=z_0+re^{i \theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ \gamma(t)=z_0+re^{it}$ for $t \in [0, 2 \pi].$

Then

$$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz= \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_0^{2 \pi}\frac{f(z_0+re^{it})}{re^{it}}ire^{it} dt= \frac{1}{2 \pi }\int_0^{2 \pi}f(z_0+re^{it}) dt.$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thank you @Fred. Yes I can.